# typescript manually narrow a union type inside a child scope

Tags: typescript

I want to force ts to narrow a union type in a situation that the compiler cannot do it itself.

also it seems that even if the compiler narrowed the union type, we need to narrow it again inside each child scope.

**example**

```
type Type = string | number 



function getType(value: any):string { 
    if(typeof value ==="string") return "string"
    else return "number"
}

function test(x:Type, y:Type): any{
 
  //error: Property 'trim' does not exist on type 'number'
  x.trim()

 //ts compiler can narrow x here 
  if(typeof x ==="string")x.trim()

 //but it cannot narrow y here; however we can confirm that type of y here is a string
  if(getType(y) !=="string")y="stringValue"

 //error, as the compiler couldn't confirm that type of y is string, but we can do.
 y.trim()

//so I want to 'manually' narrow the union type to a specific type
//I tried this code, but I don't know if there is a bettoer one
 y = y as string
 y.trim()

 //however, it doesn't work inside a scope, whitch is unexpected behaviour for me 
 //both x and y types baced to 'Type' again 
  ([] as Array<any>).forEach((item:any)=>{
     x.trim() 
     y.trim()
  })
 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `typeof` instead?

Comment: I just want to mention a case, the example above is simplified. however, I want to mention a case which the ts compiler  cannot narrow the union type.

Comment: The details of the case matter. In this code your function has two return values, so if it changed to return `true` or `false` then you could declare it as a user-defined type guard, for example. If your real problem is not like that then this would require more or different refactoring.

Comment: this is not the case I want to solve.

Comment: You need to assert `variable is SomeType` in your typechecking function.  You still have issues with the scope though https://tsplay.dev/AwQgYm